# How to get output of dig <www.domain.com> +short using ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dns

How do I get the output of a command like 'dig [www.mlb.com](http://www.mlb.com) +short' using Ruby? I realize I can simply do a system command via backticks, but is there a library that allows me to get the output without a system command?

```
dig www.mlb.com +short
```

Output:

```
www.mlb.com.edgekey.net.
e5991.dscg.akamaiedge.net.
104.77.230.52
```

I have used Resolv and DnsRuby, and can only seem to get one of the entries above. For example:

```
require 'dnsruby'
include Dnsruby

res = Resolver.new
ret = res.query('www.mlb.com', Types.CNAME)
ret.answer.map {|x| x.rdata.to_s}
```

only gives me the first line in the output

```
www.mlb.com.edgekey.net
```

Comment: Have you tried Resolv and dnsruby? https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/resolv/rdoc/Resolv/DNS.html and https://github.com/alexdalitz/dnsruby/wiki

Comment: I have used Resolv and DnsRuby, and can only seem to get one of the entries above. For example: res = Resolver.new; ret = res.query('www.mlb.com', 'Types.CNAME); ret.answer.map {|x| x.rdata.to_s} only gives me the first line in the output

Comment: Are you actually interested in the intermediate CNAMEs or do you just want to get the final list of IP addresses?

Comment: @HolgerJust What does the output above for dig <www.domain.com> + short show? I think it shows intermediate, and if so that's what i'm interested in.

Comment: Check out [Open3](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/Open3.html). It's a built-in ruby library and will give you access to both stdout and stderr. It might be overkill for your needs but it'll give you some good ideas.

Answer (score 0):

1. should add the gem 'dnsruby'

```
gem 'dnsruby'
```

and bundle install
This is a sameple model that I created

```
class Dig
  require 'dnsruby'
  include Dnsruby
  #Dig.single_resolvers
  def self.single_resolvers
    res = Resolver.new
    res.single_resolvers.each {|s| print "Server address : #{s.server}\n"}
  end
  #Dig.query(url: 'www.mlb.com', kind: 'mx')
  def self.query(url: 'www.mlb.com', kind: nil)
    res = Resolver.new
    if kind.nil?
      ret = res.query(url) # Defaults to A record
    else
      ret = res.query(url, kind) # Defaults to A record
    end
    ret.answer
  end
end
```